# Como obter o DateOnly.Now em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, data

Quando usamos o `Datetime`, podemos usara propriedade `Now` para pegar a data atual do computador. Mas na documentação do `DateOnly` não tem essa propriedade. O que fazer? Por que não tem?

Aproveitando, porque essa classe não chama apenas `Date`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De fato, não existe e não tem tanta necessidade assim, a não ser por conveniência. Basta um método que faça isso em toda a biblioteca. Se já existe o [`Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) no `DateTime` não precisa existir em outro lugar. Basta pegar dele para gerar o seu valor só de data:

```
DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)
```

Pode fazer para o [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) também da mesma forma. Pode pegar o [`Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) se preferir.

Obviamente os mesmos cuidados precisam ser tomados, porque o conceito do que é o hoje é um pouco mais complicado do que pode parecer para o leigo no assunto, e quase todos os programadores são. Uma pena não ter uma solução simples, fácil e universal.

Algumas pessoas preferem fazer um método de extensão para ter no tipo:

```
public static class DateExt {
    public static DateOnly Now(this DateOnly dateTime) => DateOnly.FromDateTime(dateTime);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DalteOnlyNow.cs).

Muitas pessoas já tinham tipos próprios chamados `Date` ou `Time` e a criação geraria algum problema. Não que fosse gerar colisão, porque dependeria de importação, mas as pessoas já estavam acostumadas, criaria problema cognitivo. E para não complicar muito teria que colocar fora do *namespace* `System`, porque ele é virtualmente importado em todos os códigos. E com o advento do `global using` complicaria mais ainda. Então usaram um nome que dificilmente alguém teria usado. Estudaram algumas possibilidades, e essa saiu vencedora.